# How to properly attach a bulk of small files to a task in graph api

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

Have the following code.

```cs
if (attachments != null)
{
    if (attachments.Length > 0)
    {
        _newTask.Attachments = new TodoTaskAttachmentsCollectionPage();
        foreach (var _attachment in attachments)
        {
            _newTask.Attachments.Add(new TaskFileAttachment
            {
                Name = _attachment.FileName,
                ContentBytes = _attachment.ContentBytes,
                ContentType = _attachment.ContentType
            });
        }
    }

}
await _graphServiceClient.Users[idUser].Todo.Lists[idList].Tasks.Request().AddAsync(_newTask);
```

Im trying to add multiple small files to a task and then post it to the graph api.

But it results in the following error:

> One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (A type
> named 'microsoft.toDo.taskFileAttachment' could not be resolved by the
> model. When a model is available, each type name must resolve to a
> valid type.

Basically saying that the type `taskFileAttachment` is not the correct type to add to the collection of attachments of a `task`.

But, according to MS[doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/todotask-post-attachments?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp) that's the correct type to add.

Cant see what i'm missing and there is not a lot of documentation of how to post small files to a task. I already done it through the api for mails and thought it was really straightforward but it looks as it is not the case.

Comment: I'm afraid that you cannot create a todo task with attachments in one request. You need to create a todo task first and then add attachments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as they commented in my original post, there is no current way to attach a collection of files in one single request. They must attached to a created task one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/todotasklist-post-tasks?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#request-body) , there are list of property that are required when you create the todoTask , in that you can't find any property to attach the file

First try to [create a new listItems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/todotasklist-post-tasks?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#http-request) , and [attach the file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/todotask-post-attachments?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp#request)

Sample to attach the file

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var attachmentBase = new TaskFileAttachment
{
    Name = "smile",
    ContentBytes = Convert.FromBase64String("a0b1c76de9f7="),
    ContentType = "image/gif"
};

await graphClient.Me.Todo.Lists["{todoTaskList-id}"].Tasks["{todoTask-id}"].Attachments
    .Request()
.AddAsync(attachmentBase);
```